# Receiving the titled error for a Meteor Galaxy deploy: MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-galaxy, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to deploy a locally developed meteor app to Galaxy (provided by meteor). I've used one of their recommended mongodb providers, Atlas by MongoDB. I have overcome several connection issues, however I cannot figure out the cause of the below. The user associated with it has atlasAdmin, dbAdmin, dbAdminAnyDatabase,readWriteAnyDatabase on the admin db "@admin".

```
/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
    throw(ex);
MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { listIndexes: "users", cursor: { } }
Object.Future.wait (/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
[object Object].MongoConnection._ensureIndex (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:832:10)
[object Object].Mongo.Collection._ensureIndex (packages/mongo/collection.js:677:20)
setupUsersCollection (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1493:9)
new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:51:5)
meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
/app/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:2031:15
/app/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:2042:3
Function.MongoError.create (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
queryCallback (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:197:34)
/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:455:18
nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:489:9)
process._tickCallback (node.js:418:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. I implemented mlab instead and just let it sit for a while.